# Show that ${d\over dt}\int_{\Phi_t(S)}\eta = \int_{\Phi_t(S)}X\lrcorner d\eta+d(X\lrcorner\eta)$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

> Suppose $S\subset K$ is an embedded oriented $k$-submanifold of orinetable smooth manifold $M$. Let $\Phi$ be a flow of some complete smooth vector field $X$ on $M$. Then,
> $$\int_{S}\Phi_t^*\eta =\int_{\Phi_t(S)}\eta,$$
> for a smooth $k$-form with compact support on $M$ and
> $${d\over dt}\int_{\Phi_t(S)}\eta = \int_{\Phi_t(S)}X\lrcorner d\eta+d(X\lrcorner\eta).$$

For the first equality, let $\{\psi_i\}$ be a smooth partition of unity subordinate to positively oriented smooth charts $\{(U_i,\varphi_i)\}$ of $M$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_S\Phi_t^*\eta & = \sum_i\int_S\psi_i\Phi_t^*\eta\\
& = \sum_i\int_{\hat{U}_i}(\varphi_i^{-1})^*(\psi_i\Phi_t^*\eta)\\
& = \sum_i\int_{\hat{U}_i}\psi_i(\varphi_i^{-1})^*(\Phi_t^*\eta)\\
& = \sum_i\int_{\hat{U}_i}\psi_i(\Phi_t\circ\varphi_i^{-1})^*\eta\\
& = \sum_i\int_{\Phi_t(S)}\psi_i\eta\\
& = \int_{\Phi_t(S)}\eta\\
\end{align*}
Here, $\Phi_t$ is positively oriented as $\Phi_0 = 1$ and by continuity on $t$, if $\omega$ is a positively oriented orientation form on $M$ then $\Phi_t^*\omega$ is a positively oriented orientation form on $M$.

For the second equality, of course, we use Cartan's formula.
\begin{align*}
{d\over dt}\bigg|_{t =t_0}\int_{\Phi_t(S)}\eta & = {d\over dt}\bigg|_{t =t_0}\int_S\Phi_t^*\eta\\
& {\color{red} =}\int_S{d\over dt}\bigg|_{t =t_0}\Phi_t^*\eta\\
& = \int_S\Phi_{t_0}^*(\mathcal{L}_X\eta)\\
& = \int_{\Phi_{t_0}(S)}\mathcal{L}_X\eta\\
& = \int_{\Phi_{t_0}(S)}X\lrcorner d\eta+\int_{\Phi_{t_0}(S)}d(X\lrcorner\eta)\\
\end{align*}

I'm not sure the red-colored equality is allowed. Can anyone please confirm I did it right?

Comment: You should ask $S$ to be orientable and declare an orientation on it. $M$ being oriented doesn't imply that $S$ might be even orientable

Comment: @Didier I'm assuming $S$ is orientable.

Comment: I have read your last sentence two times before posting the comment and still didn't see you have put "oriented"! I'm sorry about that.

Comment: After reading in details, your solution is great. The read equality can be obtained by checking what happens in charts with a partition of unity and applying usual derivation theorems for Lebesgue integral with compact support integrand( hence, reduced difficulty).